# Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit MQ fanout exchange

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

In my application I am Integrating Rabbit MQ using spring cloud stream. By default spring cloud streams creates the destination as a exchange of type topic in Rabbit MQ. How to configure spring cloud stream to create a exchange of type fanout ?

Comment: Please, explain why do you need `fanout` exchange?

Comment: We have an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/34) to provide more options over and above the current opinionated configuration.

Comment: @ArtemBilan topic needs Routing pattern. My Producer application is a java application and I am integrating with Rabbit MQ using Spring Cloud Stream. My Consumer Application is a NodeJS application which subscribes to a queue and binds the queue to the exchange created by the producer. But when the producer publishes a message to the exchanges it is not coming to the queue. The queue is always empty. I think a queue needs routing pattern while binding with an exchange which I am not able to configure using spring cloud stream. So I am using exchange of type fanout which works fine

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks. Right now I am creating the exchange manually as type fanout and then using it in spring cloud stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You definitely should bind your queue from the consumer side or Broker. That should not be Spring Cloud Stream Binder level. For your use case you can consider the binding key as a `#`:

> When a queue is bound with "#" (hash) binding key - it will receive all the messages, regardless of the routing key - like in fanout exchange.

See https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html

2. You still can use desired fanout exchange for your consumer, but the same Broker binding feature should be involved to bind your fanout exchange to this SCSt topic exchange via the same `#` key trick.

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan. This is an alternate solution / Temporary solution for the question I asked. But perfectly fits my requirements

Comment: @Artem Bilan Then what is the difference between `Fanout` and `topic + routing key #` ?

Comment: In performance. The `Fanout` doesn't do any attempts to check the `routing key`.